# Go variable struct reassignment bug?

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand the behavior of this small snippet, taken from a larger singly linked-list implementation:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Node struct {
    Next *Node
    Data string
}

func (n *Node) Link(data string) Node {
    link := Node{Data: data, Next: n}
    return link
}

func main() {
    head := Node{Data: "a"}
    head = head.Link("b")
    fmt.Printf("head = %+v\n", head)
    fmt.Printf("head.Next = %+v\n", head.Next)
}
```

Output:

```
head = {Next:0xc42000a060 Data:b}
head.Next = &{Next:0xc42000a060 Data:b}
```

Why is head.Next being linked to itself, and not the "a" node?  It has something to do with the re-assignment of the variable name "head", because if you change the line:

```
head = head.Link("b")
```

to

```
head2 := head.Link("b")
```

and printf head2, everything is correct.  Can someone shed light on this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain? I think that this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a node with data "a" and store this node in a variable head which is *not* a pointer to a Node but a Node. Then you do some weird stuff to change the data of that node and nothing else: The call to link will first get the address of your Node a (to call the pointer method). Then you create a new Node value which has Next point to the Node a. You return that node (and not a pointer to it). Then you overwrite everything in your node head with the new stuff, i.e. Data and Next.

Use pointers througout:

```
func (n *Node) Link(data string) *Node { return &Node{Data: data, Next: n} }

func main() {
    head := &Node{Data: "a"}
    fmt.Printf("head = %+v\n", *head)
    head = head.Link("b")
    fmt.Printf("head = %+v\n", *head)
    fmt.Printf("head.Next = %+v\n", *head.Next)
}
```

Comment: Aha, I get it.  My mismatched pointer/value implementation was biting me.  The value of the Node contained a reference to a pointer whose value was about to be changed to the returned Node.  Thank you!